# Fighting with -webkit-filter: blur and not solid edges (works with filter: blur)

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

[I have written this pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByZPxw)

**EDIT** [see this pen of Alexander Omara for a shorter version of my pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rawrog)

basically we set the `bg` span to always be more than full screen, even on resize. The blurry edges should be removed by using the known "use a container around the image that is smaller than the image" to cut off the blurry edges. This container has the size of the actual screen view port.

Now this works perfectly fine in the newest firefox 35.

[image]

But it fails *so hard* in webkit browsers e.g. tested in chrome 40.0.2214.91 m.

[image]

First of all, there is the green bg from body visible, after the text it disappears ?! and shows a whitish blur.

That's not even all, if you use the horizontal scroll (i don't really want a horizontal scroll actually)

[image]

The greenish background from the body *disappears* . If you scroll left again, it *reappears*. The blurry edge is coming from the edge of the browser window, next to the scrollbar, it is *not* coming from the actual image edge. You can see it by the green background, when scrolling left and right, and that the green turns into white.

Magic.

Pull the plug on this and have our webkit community fix it. Or is there a fix to this I somehow am overlooking?

Source:

HTML

```
<span class="lux-section" ><span class="bg" ></span><span><br><br><br><br><br>About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us About us about us<br></span></span>
```

CSS

```
.lux-section .bg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://s15.postimg.org/4elomwgbv/luxvitae.jpg) center center scroll no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  -webkit-filter: blur(15px);
  -moz-filter: blur(15px);
  filter: blur(15px);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  z-index: -1;
  display: inline-block;
}

body{
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0;
}
```

JS

```
      lux = {};

function reinitSizes(){
            lux.viewWidth = $(window).width()   ;
            lux.viewHeight = $(window).height() ;
  //enclosing span of the bg image and the text
            $(".lux-section").css({
                "width": lux.viewWidth,
                "height": lux.viewHeight
            });

  //resize the bg image to be bigger than it's enclosing span.
            $(".lux-section > .bg").each(function(index, bgObj){
                var blur = 15;
                var resized = blur * blur;
                $(bgObj).css({
                "width": (lux.viewWidth +   resized),
                "height": (lux.viewHeight + resized),
                "top" : Math.round(-0.5*resized),
                "left": Math.round(-0.5*resized)
            });
        });

        }

$(function(){

 reinitSizes();

  $(window).resize(function() {
                reinitSizes();
            });


});
```

Comment: Looks like WebKit is trying to do some magic optimizations and clipping the blur to the visible section. [Here's a simpler Codepen the shows off the main issue](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rawrog).

Comment: As work around... What about removing the background color of your parent element? Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNOZGg

Comment: Please have a look at this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdPXMM

Answer (score 0):

You can try  this trick.

Apply the same image you are blurring to the div container

Example here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOoNGV

```
body {
  background: black;
}
.wrap {
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
    background: white url('https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png');
}
.image {
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  top: -15px;
  bottom: -15px;
  background: white url('https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png');
  -webkit-filter: blur(15px);
     -moz-filter: blur(15px);
          filter: blur(15px);
}
```