# image mask / masked image alternative for blurred menu element?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to achieve this effect:
[image: an overlay that works as menu with blurred background of the actual content background]

the menu has position fixed and will not scroll, it will overlap and the blur should correspond to the underlying part of the image.

I checked out `filter` blur but it seems [to be buggy in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28144996/fighting-with-webkit-filter-blur-and-not-solid-edges-works-with-filter-blur), does not work at all in IE (i don't really care actually) and I am not really sure about other browsers.

I checked out as well [this link about using gradients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286550/transparent-circle-using-only-css) but it seems to apply only to round objects without a background image as possible background.

I thought about using an `mask-image` but development just isn't there yet (firefox does not support it) as it seems (again, I wouldn't care at all if IE fails, but if others fail too...)

So, what would be the best way to achieve this effect?

**EDIT**: an example image would be this one: http://img.youtube.com/vi/zXgyoDAuaH0/maxresdefault.jpg

and here the blurred image

[image]

(just open in new window and download)

it is allowed to use a generated blurred image

Comment: Can include example image link, without menu ?

Comment: I added one, but you can really use any image that you want

Comment: See http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/other/create-negative-blur-and-rotate-image-effects-using-the-html5-canvas.html

Answer (score 0):

[I ended up using js to scroll the background position](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNjadq)

HTML

```
<div class="content"> 
  <div class="menu"> x
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content{
  position: relative;
 height: 10000px;
  background: url('http://img.youtube.com/vi/zXgyoDAuaH0/maxresdefault.jpg') 0 0;
}

.menu{
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xgJ7.jpg');
  background-position: -20px -20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: fixed;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).on("scroll", function() {
  console.error();
  $(".menu").css({
    backgroundPosition: "-20px " + (-13 - $(window).scrollTop()) + "px"
  });
});
```